# Key Value Observing in Cocoa, introspecting the change property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

I'm using key value observing on a boolean property an NSObject method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context
```

The most interesting part of the value for this key path is a BOOL which is constantly flipping between YES/NO. The most I get out of the change dictionary is kind = 1. Is there anyway without probing the object I'm observing to see what the actual change value is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Firstly, you specify NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew:

```
[theObject addObserver: self
            forKeyPath: @"theKey"
               options: NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
               context: NULL];
```

…then, in your observer method:

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath: (NSString *)keyPath ofObject: (id) object
                        change: (NSDictionary *) change context: (void *) context
{
    BOOL newValue = [[change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
}
```

Ideally you'd check whether value was `nil` (well, it *might* happen) before calling `-boolValue`, but that was omitted for clarity here.

Comment: How could you get "nil"? It could happen for anything of NSObject type, but I don't see how that could happen for a BOOL?

Comment: I mean you would check whether the result of `[change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]` was `nil`, because there's a difference between 'no result' and 'a result of `NO`'.

Comment: @JimDovey - when I inspect the dictionary on the debug console for a non-BOOL property, I wonder if a string literal check isn't required as well `new = "<null>"`

Comment: Actually I found out that when a method returns an `NSNull` object, the -description on that object returns the string `<null>` so my earlier introspection based comment to check for a string literal is unmerited. I now check for `nil` like so:

        ```if ([change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] == nil ||
            [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] == (id)[NSNull null])
        {...}```

Answer (score 21):

As Jim Dovey says, except that the change dictionary does not bring nil, but null values, so that

```
NSLog(@"%@", [change description]);
```

will result in something like:

```
{
    kind = 1;
    new = <null>;
    old = <null>;
}
```

As mentioned, calling boolValue on a null value will result in an error

> [NSNull boolValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0147020

To avoid this, one has to check not for nil but for [NSNull null], like so:

```
if([change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] != [NSNull null]) 
  BOOL newValue = [[change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
```

or

```
id newValue;
if((newValue[change valueForKey: @"new"]) != [NSNull null]){
     BOOL newBOOL = [newValue boolValue];
}
```

Comment: I searched and found out this post. I have same issue that new=null returned. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11835607/772481 Is this fixed?

Comment: Doubt that this will ever get fixed. In your question you run into a problem observing a relationship, which complicates things. As I quoted there from the docs "If the observed property is a to-many relationship, the NSKeyValueChangeKindKey entry also indicates whether objects in the relationship were inserted, removed, or replaced by returning NSKeyValueChangeInsertion, NSKeyValueChangeRemoval, or NSKeyValueChangeReplacement, respectively."